# facebook graph API company page URL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on some data analysis regarding beverage manufacturers in the US and would like to grab posts from the company facebook pages to mine some data using the standard facebook graph API.  I am new to the facebook API and I am hoping to get some clarifications here that I can't find in the developer docs.

For a simple example lets look at 2 companies FB pages:

- https://www.facebook.com/CocaColaUnitedStates
- https://www.facebook.com/BellsBreweryInc

Now per the API documentation, I should be able to retrieve the posts on those public company pages via a URL as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/COMPANYFBNAMEHERE/feed?access_token=MYTOKEN

or 

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/COMPANYFBNAMEHERE/feed?access_token=MYTOKEN
```

This works for CocaCola: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/CocaColaUnitedStates/feed?access_token=MYTOKEN

This returns data as I would expect:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "message": "The French \"yes! yes! yes!\" sounds like \"we! we! we!\" (lettered \"oui.\") \"C'est la vie\" sounds like (homonym) \"say LOVIE\" (like lovie dovie).\n\nSong of (rather than \"by\") Robbie Nevil: C'est La Vie\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGtf9QfITQw",
     "created_time": "2016-02-06T02:52:17+0000",
     "id": "820882001277849_452698638250376"
  },
etc....
```

However when I try this for Bell's:  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/BellsBreweryInc/feed?access_token=MYTOKEN

I get this:

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "AWTxWye6vub"
}
}
```

I am not understanding why I am getting an error on Bell's page?  It's a publicly available company FB page, so I can't imagine it's a restriction, but I can't understand why it wouldn't be returning the posts like CocaCola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Age restircted websites require a user access token from a user account that meets the page requirements.  I was using an app access token which is why it didn't work.

I needed to log into my account and generate a user access token and use that token in the URL.

Also, just realized that token expires in a couple hours.  Anyone wanting to do this may also want to read this: [How to extend facebook access token in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002691/how-to-extend-facebook-access-token-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the owner of the token you are using is below the legal drinking age. BellsBreweryInc is a page in the alcohol category so no data will be returned for users under the legal age. This is something BellsBreweryInc would have set in their page settings.

[image: Page settings]

Comment: How do I generate a token that specifies the age limit?  The FB account I am using for my app, that the app token was generated with, has my birthday in it's profile, and I turned 21 well over a decade ago.

Comment: nevermind, found the answer!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747155/use-facebook-app-access-token-to-get-age-restricted-page-data-through-graph-api

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction though!!!  I'm in my 30's so I never run into any age restrictions browsing FB, so this never even crossed my mind :(